# Camera Preview Example

Tags: java, android

I know this is really basic but it is a error that I cannot find a solution to.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

I have 2 errors and I dont know what Im doning wrong.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate our menu which can gather user input for switching camera
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.camera_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Im getting an error at "menu" in "R.menue..."

error 2:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.switch_cam:
            // check for availability of multiple cameras
            if (numberOfCameras == 1) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                /**builder.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.camera_alert))
                       .setNeutralButton("Close", null);*/
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                return true;
}
```

Im getting an error on "id" in "case R.id..."

Thanks

Comment: Two points you need to add extra info on in order for us to answer this. Are they compiler errors or runtime? What are the actual errors? If they're compiler errors, do you actually have the R.menu.camera_menu and R.id.switch_cam defined? If it's runtime, then those defined assets probably have typos

Comment: first try to clean your project from project->Clean and if you have this line `import com.example.android.apis.R;` then just remove it..

Comment: Well it says not resolved or it is not a field. I just dont know how to create this.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`in your `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

You can try to check a full Camera preview here for Android : [Camera Preview Android](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html)

Another good website with source files : [Using Camera API with SourceFile](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesmultimedia/278-using-camera-api-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely just copied the source file you linked above into your project. You also have to add [`res/menu/camera_menu.xml`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/menu/camera_menu.html). This defines the options menu that comes up when you press the menu button. See the [menu doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) for more information how that works if you're interested.

If you don't do that the tools notice that you miss a file that you reference in code but that's not actually there, which results the first error. The second error is also caused by this in an indirect way. The missing ID is also created within the menu file.

Comment: Ok cool Im figuring this out. Thank!

is there also an xml file I need to create for the alert and switch_cam?

Comment: @dcarney999 Oh I see you commented that out. The alert makes use of a string named `camera_alert`. This has to be defined in `res/values/strings.xml`. You should have that by default, just add the relevant entry. The [orginal file](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/strings.html) has a lot of unneccessary entries, you don't most of these. But you can copy that file over as well instead if you prefer. The rest should just work.

Comment: ok I got the id thing (I hope)

its not liking import com.example.android.apis.R;

do you have a link with a good explanation for this or what i need to do, maybe change it

Comment: Get rid of that import line and it should be fine. Since you copied the files over, all the definitions should be in the R class in your projects package.

Comment: So I think im really close. I think im still stuck with the switch_cam I tried forcing it into the R.java file so it shows no errors. Then when I run it, I get a warning saying there are errors...